# How do I install Namecheap SSL in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, ssl, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I use Firebase hosting for my website and have connected it to my custom domain on Namecheap.
Because Firebase provides a weird shared SSL on it's own, I bought an SSL certificate from Namecheap. I got the CSR from Google Cloud Platform, activated it and installed the .zip file for the SSL installation.
Now I don't know how to install it in firebase. The Namecheap guide only explaines it for Google Cloud Platform application engine, which I am not using.
I couldn't find anything adressing this.

How do I install my SSL .zip file on my website if I am using Namecheap and Firebase?

Edit: When I'm on my dashboard on Namecheap my domain has that red SSL symbol next to it and it says that is is actived. When I click on manage it says that I need to install it. So yeah. I think it's activated but not installed on my website.

[image: The message when I manage my active SSL in Namecheap]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting only supports its own provisioned SSL certs, as described in detail in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).  You can't add one of your own.

Comment: Oh. But my certificate is for a random website called "www.cheesusburger.at".
Does everbody get a really random SSL with no way to change it? 
It seems very unprofessional to have cheesusburger.at as your certificate.
What do other websites and businesses do?

Comment: I can only recommend that you reach out to Firebase support directly if you have concerns about Firebase Hosting that are not covered in the documentation.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support